# Recycle view isn’t scrolling after updating adapter with values from database

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a homepage layout with a recycle view that scrolls vertically but for some reason after I populate it with DB data it stops scrolling(i see that the remaining data is loading below the viewport but I can’t scroll up to see them and i have other components in the layout which is why I can’t set the recycle view height to “match parent”. The recycle view is set to vertical layout manager too.

I’ve tried nestedscrollview but that just restricted it to 1 cardview which scrolls but i want a list that displays multiple card( I can’t use “match parent” cus of other view components in the layout) and adding an inner container didn’t fix it either

This is the xml layout (the recycleview with id = product_View is the issue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    android:background="#Fffdd0"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#FF6200EE"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </TextView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titsub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Search through... "
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tit">


    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Categories"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titsub">

    </TextView>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/category_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#Fffdd0"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category"
        tools:itemCount="1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/design">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Popular"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_view">

    </TextView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/product_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#Fffdd0"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        tools:itemCount="3"
        tools:listitem="@layout/design2">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code that gets data and populates the recycleview

```
private fun getData() {

        //val loading = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.loadingPage)

        val ref = db.collection("popular")
        val list = ArrayList<data2>()

        ref.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (doc in result) {
                    val id = doc.id

                    // getting business Info
                    ref.document(id)
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                            if (document != null) {
                                val n = document.data?.get("name").toString()
                                val r = document.data?.get("rating").toString()?.toFloat()
                                val d = document.data?.get("description").toString()
                                Log.d("TAG", n)

                                //passing result to new list
                                list.add(
                                    data2(
                                        R.drawable.photography_img,
                                        n,
                                        d,
                                        r
                                    )
                                )

                                Log.d("TAG data", list.toString())
                                //clearing the placeholder data and feeding it the result from the Database
                                data2.clear()
                                data2.addAll(list)
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                             //   loading?.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", exception)
            }
    }
```

[image: The recycle_view below "popular" is the issue...not scrolling]

Comment: add some code? so that we can get a perspective.

Comment: Yh…I’ve added em now. Thanks